# Comparing values in Python data frame efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trading daily on Cryptocurrencies and would like to find which are the most desirable Cryptos for trading.
I have CSV file for every Crypto with the following fields:

```
Date           Sell       Buy
43051.23918    1925.16    1929.83
43051.23919    1925.12    1929.79
43051.23922    1925.12    1929.79
43051.23924    1926.16    1930.83
43051.23925    1926.12    1930.79
43051.23926    1926.12    1930.79
43051.23927    1950.96    1987.56
43051.23928    1190.90    1911.56
43051.23929    1926.12    1930.79
```

I would like to check:

How many quotes will end with profit:

1. for Buy positions - if one of the following Sells > current Buy.
2. for Sell positions - if one of the following Buys < current Sell.

How much time it would take to a theoretical position to become profitable.

What can be the profit potential.

I'm using the following code:

```
#converting from OLE to datetime
OLE_TIME_ZERO = dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0)
def ole(oledt):
    return OLE_TIME_ZERO + dt.timedelta(days=float(oledt))

#variables initialization
buy_time = ole(43031.57567) - ole(43031.57567)
sell_time = ole(43031.57567) - ole(43031.57567)
profit_buy_counter = 0
no_profit_buy_counter = 0
profit_sell_counter = 0
no_profit_sell_counter = 0

max_profit_buy_positions = 0
max_profit_buy_counter = 0

max_profit_sell_positions = 0
max_profit_sell_counter = 0

df = pd.read_csv("C:/P/Crypto/bitcoin_test_normal_276k.csv")

#comparing to max
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = index + 1
    df_slice = df[a:]
    if df_slice["Sell"].max() - row["Buy"] > 0:
        max_profit_buy_positions += df_slice["Sell"].max() - row["Buy"]
        max_profit_buy_counter += 1
    for index1, row1 in df_slice.iterrows():
        if row["Buy"] < row1["Sell"]  :
            buy_time += ole(row1["Date"])- ole(row["Date"]) 
            profit_buy_counter += 1
            break
    else:
            no_profit_buy_counter += 1

#comparing to sell
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = index + 1
    df_slice = df[a:]
    if  row["Sell"] - df_slice["Buy"].min() > 0:
        max_profit_sell_positions += row["Sell"] - df_slice["Buy"].min()
        max_profit_sell_counter += 1        
    for index2, row2 in df_slice.iterrows():    
        if row["Sell"] > row2["Buy"] :
            sell_time += ole(row2["Date"])- ole(row["Date"])
            profit_sell_counter += 1  
            break
    else:
        no_profit_sell_counter += 1         

num_rows = len(df.index)

buy_avg_time = buy_time/num_rows
sell_avg_time = sell_time/num_rows

if max_profit_buy_counter == 0:
    avg_max_profit_buy = "There is no profitable buy positions"
else:    
    avg_max_profit_buy = max_profit_buy_positions/max_profit_buy_counter

if max_profit_sell_counter == 0:
    avg_max_profit_sell = "There is no profitable sell positions"
else:
   avg_max_profit_sell = max_profit_sell_positions/max_profit_sell_counter
```

The code works fine for 10K-20K lines but for a larger amount (276K) it take a long time (more than 10 hrs)

What can I do in order to improve it?

Is there any "Pythonic" way to compare each value in a data frame to all following values?

note - the dates in the CSV are in OLE so I need to convert it to Datetime.

File for testing:
Thanks for your comment.
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SH_9DVIJnNzE1L4ykoCnjdSg_bcEDIp_/view?usp=sharing) you can find the file that I used:

Comment: You might want to include the csv (or a smaller test version of it) for us to try out your program, and verify our solution.

Comment: Thank you. I have attached the file to my question.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd want to create the cumulative maximum/minimum values for `Sell` and `Buy` per row, so it's easy to compare to. `pandas` has `cummax` and `cummin`, but they go the wrong way. So we'll do:

```
df['Max Sell'] = df[::-1]['Sell'].cummax()[::-1]
df['Min Buy'] = df[::-1]['Buy'].cummin()[::-1]
```

Now, we can just compare each row:

```
df['Buy Profit'] = df['Max Sell'] - df['Buy']
df['Sell Profit'] = df['Sell'] - df['Min Buy']
```

I'm positive this isn't exactly what you want as I don't perfectly understand what you're trying to do, but hopefully it leads you in the right direction.

After comparing your function and mine, there is a slight difference, as your `a` is offset one off the index. Removing that offset, you'll see that my method produces the same results as yours, only in vastly shorter time:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = index
    df_slice = df[a:]
    assert (df_slice["Sell"].max() - row["Buy"]) == df['Max Sell'][a] - df['Buy'][a]
else:
    print("All assertions passed!")
```

Note this will still take the very long time required by your function. Note that this can be fixed with `shift`, but I don't want to run your function for long enough to figure out what way to shift it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I'm not interested in finding the "global" maximum/minimum as it probably will give me the wrong answer but the following maximum/minimum. just for example - there is a possibility that every row will have a different maximum/minimum.

Comment: This does not find the "global" maximum. By using `cummax`, we only get the `maximum` of all of the values proceeding that row. Since we apply it to a reversed matrix, when we reverse it again, we obtain the largest value after and including a certain row. If you run what I gave you, you will see that the 'Max Sell' and 'Min Buy' columns change by row.

Comment: Therefore, `df['Max Sell'] - df['Buy'` is equivalent to `df_slice["Sell"].max() - row["Buy"]` for any row.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll try it. Thanks !

Comment: I added a comparison between your function and my function so you can see they run (almost) identically.

Comment: I have tried the solution you suggested but there are 2 things that are still missing.
I would like to know how much time passed till buy < sell for every row and how many times it happened.
For example, I would like to test if:

Buy(x) < Sell (x+i) [i from 1 till n]

is there any elegant way to do it?